# Why do JavaScript errors seem to not get detected in Visual Studio Code console?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm new and learning from FreeCodeCamp, their editor runs the code below and displays "
ReferenceError: sTr1 is not defined" [screenshot here](http://prntscr.com/11dcbb4)

However, with Visual Studio Code, and even here in stackoverflow, the code executes without a problem ([screenshot from VSC](http://prntscr.com/11dclmr)).

I am curious why there is a difference. I also expect the error because of what I learned from another language (Java), that it cannot be used unless the variable was declared first.

```js
var str1 = "hi";
sTr1 = "hey";
console.log(sTr1);
```

Comment: Well, in Javascript you CAN use a variable before it's declared

Comment: ... but the fact is, that you haven't declared `sTr1`, it's an "implicit global", which is an error in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#converting_mistakes_into_errors).

Comment: From what I understood from the replies, with the case of the console in FreeCodeCamp, the error is because it is in strict mode? While the reason it still works in other editors is it is in non-strict mode in which "declaration" of the variable does not matter. Is that correct?

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please mark the correct answer. If not, please comment accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a value to a variable which hasn't been declared creates a global variable with that name automatically in non-strict mode, and throws a `ReferenceError` in strict mode.

Please note that ES modules are *always* in strict mode.

```html
<script type="module">
  foo = "foo"; 
  console.log(foo); // ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable foo
</script>

<script>
  bar = "bar"; 
  console.log(bar); // "bar"
</script>

<script>
  "use strict";
  baz = "baz";
  console.log(baz); // ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable baz
</script>
```